# Loading files from GCS to BigQuery - what's the best approach?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I need to load around 1 million rows into bigquery table.  My approach will be to write data into cloud storage, and then use load api to load multiple files at once.
What's the most efficient way to do this?  I can parallelize the writing into gcs part.  When I call load api, I pass in all the uris so I only need to call it once.  I'm not sure how this loading is conducted in the backend.  If I pass in multiple file names, will this loading run in multiple processes?  How do I decide the size of each file to get the best performance?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Put all the million rows in one file. If the file is not compressed, BigQuery can read it in parallel with many workers.

From https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy

- BigQuery can read compressed files (.gz) of up to 4GB.
- BigQuery can read uncompressed files (.csv, .json, ...) of up to 5000GB. BigQuery figures out how to read it in parallel - you don't need to worry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So manually splitting file into multiple will not speed it up?